# Dependency injection php website

Tags: php, dependency-injection, web, dependencies, code-injection

The more I read about dependency injection the more I get confused. I know what it is for, that is not the problem. Trying to do some design on paper this is what I came up with and somehow it seems to me I am overlooking something.

First I imagined building an actual server that would accept incoming requests and returns responses to the user.

```
class Server {
  private $responseBuilder;

  public function __construct($responseBuilder) {
    $this->responseBuilder = $responseBuilder;
  }

  public function run() {
    // create socket, receive request
    $response = $this->responsebuilder->build($request);
    // send response
  }
}

class Response {
  private $method;
  private $message;
  private $url;

  // getters & setters
}

class ServerBuilder {
   public build() {
      // construction logic
      return new Server(new ResponseBuilder());
   }
}
```

Since Apache is used to handle server requests we could replace the server with something that just send the response.

```
$bldr = new ResponseBuilder();
$response = $bldr->build();
// send response some way
```

Note that ResponseBuilder has direct access to the request ($_SERVER['..'])
and so it has everything it needs to choose the right response.

PHP however allows us to build and send responses inline. So we could have a Controller object for each page or something else that send the response and have a builder for that.

```
$bldr = new ControllerBuilder();  
$controller = $bldr->build();
$controller->run();

class ExampleController implements Controller {
    public function run() {
       header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
       echo 'sorry, page not found';
    }
}
```

---

This all makes sense to me. But let's look at the server example again.
It calls $responseBuilder->build() and gets a response back. But this would mean that the builder (or other builders if we split it) is also responsible for anything else that might occur like authenticating a user, writing to the database,... and I can't get my head around the fact that writing to a database would be part of the object graph construction.
It would be like: Send me your request. Oh you want the homepage? I will build you your response and while I'm at it I will also do some things that have nothing to do with building it like logging what I just did and saving some of your data in a cookie and sending a mail to the administrator that you are the first visitor on this page ever, ...

Comment: Let me get this right, you want to use this as a backend. Send requests to it with any data, find the page matching the data, and display it?

Comment: Isn't everything in php the backend? Anyway. This how I see it. Since it is the web there is in theory no use for setters since everything can be injected in the constructor. The main purpose of an incoming http request is to give back some html. Dependency injection is used to assemble the html by using Builders or Factories that inject everything in the constructors. But during the assembly some side effects must  be done like writing to a database and I don't believe that it is the task of a builder

Comment: Not really, You could use PHP to create the interface only( front end ), or you could use it to save things in a database or to handle model data (back end)

Comment: But isn't building an interface on the server still a backend job? Anyway yes, that is basically what I want. Getting an incoming http request, build the interface and send the http response. 
My theoretical example would do this with buildResponse(). The question is where do the side effects belong. If not in the interface building process then where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should decouple them. You have a few assumptions that I think are a bit strange. Let's start with them.

> The main purpose of an incoming http request is to give back some html

I have built PHP backends that only return JSON, instead of HTML. I had a really strong border between back and front end. I only used the backend to give me data from the database, or add/edit data in the databse. The front end was just a PHP script that would build the pages any way i wanted.

> Since it is the web there is in theory no use for setters since
>   everything can be injected in the constructor

You could use the constructor, but you don't have too. You can use setters. Dependency injection is actually just turning the flow around.

You are on the right track though. You want some class that is responsible for building your pages. So, make it only responsible for your building your pages, and take out the other responsibilities. Things like logging, authentication etc should be outside of that.

For instance if you want logging, you could have your builder create your page, and your logger could then listen to all the things your builder is doing (with the observer pattern for instance). So if your builder says: "i created the home page", you can log it with your logger, who is actually listening to your builder.

Authentication for instance should happen even before your builder starts. You don't want your builder to go to work if you can already figure out that a user is not supposed to be on a page. You could use a database for that, and whitelist any usertype/pagerequest combination.

Then for data handling, i would create a backend, that only handles requests that are supposed to give back data, or save it. The front end could then communicate to get it's content by pulling it.

I hope this clears up a few things, but I'll be happy to answer more indept questions.

Comment: In this case in would just return html but what I mean is that the main purpose is to return a response. Let it be html, a redirect, json, ... What this idea I've built my example. 
Server gets request. Server builds response. Server returns response. And then I got confused because when it builds the response it could log. 
But yes, I think I see the point of serverside backend and frontend seperation.

Comment: Well to really answer your question, obey the single responsibility principle as much as you can. This counts for classes, but also for functions. Once you find that a class is doing two things, create three classes out of it. Two for the two things it does, and the third to actually make sure both of them are given the data they need, and handle the data they're supposed too.

Comment: So what I could do is sort of like the input/output socket streams and inject them (tell don't ask principle) and let another class handle sending the response and not asking to build one and then return it (basically php echo). 
  
This way I can have an object RequestHandler that can split its concerns. One path logs, another path sends the response.

Comment: Sounds like a decent solution.